# jQuery validation onblur textarea vs other input issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having trouble getting the jQuery validation plugin to validate single input elements on blur or lose focus. Apparently this should be default behaviour but was broken by the latest version of jQuery.

Now I've tried using

> onfocusout: function(element){$(element).valid();}

And that works for textarea fields. But not for my text input fields.
Why is this and how do I get it to work?

http://jsfiddle.net/zGR5Q/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#formId').validate({
                    onfocusout: function(element)
                    {
                        $(element).valid();
                    }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="formId" method="get" action="">

<input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" /><br />
<input id="cemail" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" /><br />
<textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" cols="22"  class="required"></textarea> <br />
<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to write

```
 <input type='text'....
```

and it works